# Fechar Interstitial Ad programaticamente

Tags: android

Eu queria fechar o meu ad do tipo Interstitial após 30 segundos, caso o usuário não feche manualmente.
Tentei fechar simulando o botão back pressionado, mas não tem efeito nenhum.

```
public void onFinish() {
  Log.d(TAG, "terminou timer pausa 30s");
  dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
  //rodarvideo();
}
```

É possível fechar programaticamente? se sim, como faço?

Comment: Qual AD você está gerando? não tem nada na documentação deles?

Comment: To usando o admob mesmo, procurei e não tem nada citando sobre fechar.

Comment: Procurei e achei esse mesmo código que você está utilizando, aonde você chama essa linha de código?

Comment: Não há uma forma nativa de fechar o interstitial programaticamente, pelo menos de acordo com a documentação oficial. O máximo que você vai conseguir é através desses "hacks" de simular o botão "back" (que inclusive você já tentou), mas não há garantias que irá funcionar sempre.

Comment: @Paulo no finish no countdowntimer

Comment: @MárcioOliveira nao consigo simular um click no botão de fechar?

Comment: O problema é que você não controla o conteúdo dos ad's. Alguns tem botão de fechar (que aparecem em posições diversas), outros um timer, etc. E acredito que a filosofia do ad é fazer com que o usuário interaja com o mesmo, então fazer o próprio app fechar o ad vai meio contra isso.

Comment: Entendi. vou explicar isso pro cliente